# retrieve count in php

Tags: php, count

I need to retrieve the count of a field name called remark corresponding to a particular user.

```
select count(remark) from attendance where username=_POST['username']
```

How will I implement this in php? I need to store the count to a variable `$totalcount`.

This is what i tried out:

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM attendance where stud_id='$_POST['user']'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row[0];
```

Comment: Why are you using `1` for count when you want to count the `remark` column? Do `count(remark)`

Comment: That's what you tried out. What happened?

Comment: its allowed as is count(*)

Comment: I also believe your query string contains an error... should be `"select count(1) FROM attendance where stud_id='{$_POST['user']}'"`. I imagine all the single-quotes you have in there will cause problems.

Comment: Sidenote: [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) is imminent. It's almost as lethal as a shot in the arm.

Answer (score 0):

Also quotes are not used properly in the query string. Try this code.

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(*) FROM attendance where stud_id='".$_POST['user']."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row[0];
```